# Getting HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions when attempting to update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I'm trying to update an element in my table using Hibernate, but I get the following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open
>   Sessions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

DAO:

```
    @Override
public Demande getDemandeById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session;
     try {
         session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

    Demande d = (Demande) session.load(Demande.class, new Integer(id));
    return d;
}
@Override
public void updateDemande(Demande d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session;
     try {
         session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

    session.update(d);

    logger.info("Person updated successfully, Person Details="+d);
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("rh/editProfilDemande")
public String  RHEditProfilForm(Model m, @RequestParam int id_demande) {  
    this.profil_id = pf.getIdProfil();
    Demande d = demandeService.getDemandeById(id_demande);
    this.idDemande = id_demande; 

    m.addAttribute("profil", pf);

    m.addAttribute("demande", d); 
    return "RHEditProfil";


}   

@PostMapping("rh/editProfilDemande")
public String  RHEditProfil(Model m, Profil pf) {
    Demande d= demandeService.getDemandeById(this.idDemande);



    demandeService.updateDemande(d);
     m.addAttribute("demande",d);
    return "RHDemandeTraiteSuccess";


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening new sessions but you are never closing them if this part of code gets executed:

```
session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
```

If you really want to keep this logic:

```
  try {
     session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
```

you have to make sure you add `session.close()` after you finish work and after the `openSession()` has been used instead of `getCurrentSession()`;